# How to run UIAutomator2 commands from adb shell?

Tags: android, adb, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

Probably a stupid question, but I want to verify the answer is negatory:

Can one run `UIAutomator2` commands from `adb shell` without launching an instrumented test class?

So far all I can seem to do is dump the XML and parse it, but I wonder if I can call individual commands.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR; No, for almost all of the actions/available methods that `UiAutomator2` has, you cannot use `adb shell uiautomator xyzcommands`.**

Running `adb shell uiautomator --help` will show you the available subcommands:

```
adb shell uiautomator --help
Usage: uiautomator <subcommand> [options]

Available subcommands:

help: displays help message

runtest: executes UI automation tests
    runtest <class spec> [options]
    <class spec>: <JARS> < -c <CLASSES> | -e class <CLASSES> >
      <JARS>: a list of jar files containing test classes and dependencies. If
        the path is relative, it's assumed to be under /data/local/tmp. Use
        absolute path if the file is elsewhere. Multiple files can be
        specified, separated by space.
      <CLASSES>: a list of test class names to run, separated by comma. To
        a single method, use TestClass#testMethod format. The -e or -c option
        may be repeated. This option is not required and if not provided then
        all the tests in provided jars will be run automatically.
    options:
      --nohup: trap SIG_HUP, so test won't terminate even if parent process
               is terminated, e.g. USB is disconnected.
      -e debug [true|false]: wait for debugger to connect before starting.
      -e runner [CLASS]: use specified test runner class instead. If
        unspecified, framework default runner will be used.
      -e <NAME> <VALUE>: other name-value pairs to be passed to test classes.
        May be repeated.
      -e outputFormat simple | -s: enabled less verbose JUnit style output.

dump: creates an XML dump of current UI hierarchy
    dump [--verbose][file]
      [--compressed]: dumps compressed layout information.
      [file]: the location where the dumped XML should be stored, default is
      /sdcard/window_dump.xml

events: prints out accessibility events until terminated
```

However I found this very useful Gist with most (if not all) `adb` commands:  https://gist.github.com/Pulimet/5013acf2cd5b28e55036c82c91bd56d8

Also you can check yourself what commands are available running:

`adb shell toybox --long | tr " " "\n"`

Should you need to interact, look into `adb shell sendevent`

Comment: The source code is here: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/cmds/uiautomator/cmds/uiautomator/src/com/android/commands/uiautomator/RunTestCommand.java